# Elegant way to show details in a listview in android

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm trying to implement the following listView:

- ListElement1
- ListElement2
- ListElement3 (currently selected)

  - Some Details of
    List Element 3
    (maybe including
    another view)
- ListElement 4

I hope my question is easy to understand: How is it possible, to add some special information (these information are very long sometimes).

I can realise this by using ExpendableListViews with only one child element for each listelement... but I find this possibility not good.

Can someone help me?

Thank you!

Comment: That one child element could be a layout. And can contain thus many grandchildren elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you'll need an [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)

From the documentation:

> A view that shows items in a vertically scrolling two-level list. This
>   differs from the ListView by allowing two levels: groups which can
>   individually be expanded to show its children. The items come from the
>   ExpandableListAdapter associated with this view.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! So every item of my level-one list should have another list which contains only one level-two element?

Comment: Yeah i know, but in my case, I just want to show details from my selected element. So I will have only one element in this list - the element with my details ;)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to use a ExpandableListView or extend a fragment or activity using ListFragment or ListActivity.

Then use a custom ListAdapter, or CursorAdapter, or wherever you are getting your data from so you can override the default "list view" and create your own custom "list view" with the elements laid out however you want.